Infer a TypeScript type based on functional React component?
With Typescript and React is it possible the infer a type based on an extra property that I provide along with a functional component?
Here is (a simplified version of) my code:
const openModal = (element) => {
    // ...
}

// Define the components with their specific resultType:
const SomeModal: React.FC & { resultType: boolean } = () => <div />;
SomeModal.resultType = true;

const SomeOtherModal: React.FC & { resultType: string } = () => <div />;
SomeOtherModal.resultType = "string";

let someResult = openModal(<SomeModal />);
let someOtherResult = openModal(<SomeOtherModal />);

The code here is simplified but assume that there are a lot of different types of Modals and that openModal has no clue of which type of Modal comes in
Is there a way to infer that someResult wil be a boolean type and someOtherResult will be a string type based on the resultType of the element that I'm supplying to openModal?
I've tried a lot of options using generics with the openModal function but in all cases the someResult and someOtherResult always had a type of any or unknown.
If the type can somehow be infered on the functional component alone (so without using resultType) that would be even better
Note: I have my code working just fine but it's the TypeScript that I'm concerned with.

I believe what you want are conditional types

@Jayce444 I don't see how
I clarified the question somewhat in that there an unknown number of Modals and openModal has no clue about them
I don't think in that case conditionals are the way to go (but I'd like to be proven wrong of course)

I don't think this is possible because ms/TS#14729 hasn't been implemented (it says "fixed" but it's not, the linked PR doesn't implement this, and the issue is still open). You can't make <Foo/> and <Bar/> produce different types, they're always JSX.Element... which means you can't inspect that to get the info you need. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I was hoping there was some solution I overlooked, but with the lack of answers I'm starting to think you are correct.

I think modifying the implementation of openModal could produce the inferred results you want.

@ScottZ It couldn't possibly, because the types of <SomeModal /> and <SomeOtherModal /> are identical. Therefore, no matter what openModal() does, it cannot distinguish those inputs.

Maybe something in the line of openModal(SomeModal, props) (and then let the function generate the JSX Element) could potentialy work. But that would be too much work for its purpose.
For the time being I added generics to the openModal funciton so I can call it like this:  openModal<SomeModalType>(<SomeModal />);. A bit more hassle but it works good enough for me.

Meaning that you can write anything you want, like openModal<TheWrongModalType>(<SomeModal />), right? It's equivalent to a type assertion. Sure, you could do that

@jcalz indeed; not the nicest solution but good enough for me :)

@jcalz From the snippets provided, it is unclear if openModal returns a stateful value, or is expected to be called in a sync/async manner.  I have a project that has an async confirm util that can be called within a function body and will await a user interaction.  That util returns Promise<boolean>. I have trivially modified the util to take a component as an argument and infer the return type the util from the components props, so now it returns Promise<T>.   I would imagine openModal could be converted to do the same, but would need to know more about its functionality

Unfortunately this is not currently possible in TypeScript with JSX. Even though the components SomeModal and SomeOtherModal have different types, the JSX elements <SomeModal /> and <SomeOtherModal /> have the same type, which is JSX.Element. So no matter how you write the call signature for openModal(), the argument to openModal() will not have the information you need. You're stuck.
There is a longstanding open feature request in GitHub at microsoft/TypeScript#14729 to allow some way of distinguishing the type of JSX elements based on their contents. Maybe someday it will be implemented, and the chance of that presumably increases with an increase in community demand. So anyone who wants to see this happen might like to go to that issue and give it a . But until and unless such a feature is introduced, you can't do this with JSX.

You might work around it by giving up on JSX and calling createElement() instead, at which point you could use module augmentation to overload createElement() such that the information you care about is propagated:
import React from 'react';
declare module 'react' {
    function createElement<P extends {}, T>(
        type: React.FunctionComponent<P> & { resultType: T },
        props?: React.Attributes & P | null,
        ...children: React.ReactNode[]
    ): React.FunctionComponentElement<P> & { __resultType: T };
}

That's just one possible way to do that; presumably __resultType will not really be present at runtime (but neither is resultType in your example code).  And then your someModal could use that propagated information:
const openModal = <T extends JSX.Element & {__resultType: any}>(element: T) => {
    return null! as T["__resultType"]; // not sure how you'd implement this
}

And finally your code behaves as expect if you give up on JSX:
const SomeModal: React.FC & { resultType: boolean } = () => <div />;
SomeModal.resultType = true;

let someResult = openModal(React.createElement(SomeModal)); // boolean

const SomeOtherModal: React.FC & { resultType: string } = () => <div />;
SomeOtherModal.resultType = "string";

let someOtherResult = openModal(React.createElement(SomeOtherModal)); // string

Playground link to code

Generics! If I understand your problem correctly, something like this should get you what you're looking for:
function openModal<T extends { resultType: unknown}>(arg: T): T["resultType"]{
    if (typeof arg.resultType === "string")
        console.log("String!")

    if (typeof arg.resultType === 'boolean')
        console.log("Boolean!")
    return arg.resultType
};

const someResult = openModal({resultType:true})
const someOtherResult = openModal({resultType:"Im a string!"})

The T would be replaced by whatever type you would like to narrow it down to, from your example it would be React.FC
Heres a link the playground link if you want to mess with it

You are overlooking the fact that the argument I'm in putting in is a JSX Element

T can be anything, as long as it extends the shape of {resultType:unknown} which your provided code examples do.  React.FC & { resultType: string } & React.FC & { resultType: boolean } are valid types for T.  Your question provided no implementation for those elements, so I don't believe one should be provided in the answer.

The problem here is that openModal(<SomeModal />) (what I need) is not the same as openModal(SomeModal) (what you suggest)

Can you provide the implementation of openModal ?
